# Character of U(4) irreducible representation.

Tags: representation-theory

Is there a simple way to express the character of U(4) irreducible representation with highest weight (3, 2, 1, 0) in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials? There is an obvious solution to obtain corresponding Schur polynomial and expand it to elementary symmetric polynomials. But this will take a lot of time (since the Shur polynomial has 64 summands). This problem was a part of written exam so there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: Which basis are you writing the highest weight in?

Comment: Isn't the highest weight independent of choosing a particular basis?

Comment: The weight itself is, yes. But what the thing you wrote actually means depends entirely on the chosen basis.

Comment: It seems that if we consider the character as generating function for dimensions of weight subspaces it will also be invariant.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. The highest weight is an element in a certain vector space. You have written it as a tuple, i.e. in some specific basis. Which basis that is will be important for knowing which weight you actually mean.

Comment: By writing a tuple I meant that there is the induced representation of algebra gl(4, C), and the i_th element of tuple is the number by which the matrix element E_ii multiplies the highest weight vector.

Comment: Hmm, I was not aware that you had an action of the full $gl_4$, since this is larger than the Lie algebra of $U(4)$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, gl(4) is the complexification of Lie algebra u(4). It seems to me that there is a correspondence between their representations.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Sorry about that. So remind me, in this basis, is the partition corresponding to the highest weight simply the thing written, or is the thing written obtained as the consecutive differences of the terms of the partition?

Comment: It is the thing written.

Comment: Well, I learned about Jacobi-Trudi identities, which allow to solve the problem easily, but still it's interesting if there's an approach from representation theory.